# How to resolve gulp/glob-parent vulnerabilities?

Tags: node.js, angular, security, npm, npm-vulnerabilities

**I have been getting vulnerabilities in internal dependency `glob-parent` package of npm package - `gulp`.**

```
High            glob-parent before 5.1.2 vulnerable to Regular Expression
                  Denial of Service in enclosure regex

Package         glob-parent

Patched in      >=5.1.2

Dependency of   gulp [dev]

Path            gulp > glob-watcher > chokidar > glob-parent
```

I have gone through other questions as well regarding the same topic but I am unsure that those ways will keep the application working as it is now as I have seen different versions of `glob-parent` in `package-lock.json`.

Those suggested to use `overrides` property in package.json for `glob-parent` or add `glob-parent` to `resolutions` section.
Also, it has been found that this is a `false positive` vulnerability which is only reported in case of `NPM` not `Yarn`.
Due to some reasons, I will have to use `NPM` only.

Please suggest a way to get rid of these vulnerabilities where it should not affect the application.